# ¿Cómo convertir un ChipGroup como si fuese un radioButton en Android usando Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

tengo un `ChipGroup` con varios `Chip` en su interior, tengo definido `app:singleSelection="true"`, de esa forma solo permite una selección, pero la perculiridad de los chips es que permite que un elemento se deseleccione a si mismo y eso es lo que quiero evitar, más o menos quiero que se comporte como un `radioButton` que siempre hay un elemento seleccionado.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedChip="@id/chipSystemPackages"
    app:singleLine="true"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chipAllPackages"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chipSystemPackages"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="System" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chipUserPackages"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User" />

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de conseguir que un grupo de `Chip` se comporte como si fuesen un grupo de `RadioButton`

```
private var lastCheckedId = View.NO_ID
...
lastCheckedId = chip_group.checkedChipId
chip_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, chipId ->
    if (chipId == View.NO_ID) {
        // User tried to uncheck, make sure to keep the chip checked
        chipGroup.check(lastCheckedId)
        return@setOnCheckedChangeListener
    }
    lastCheckedId = chipId

}
```

**Update**
Por lo visto las novedades que traerá la versión `material:1.2.0-alpha02`

Para evitar que se desmarquen todos los chips, se puede usar la propiedad `app:selectionRequiredd` con valor `true`

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        ... 
        app:singleSelection="true">
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        ...
```

O bien usando código con el método `setSelectionRequired`

```
chipGroup.setSelectionRequired(true)
```

Solución extraída del siguiente hilo [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155035/chipgroup-single-selection)